# Damping coefficient

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I'm trying to investigate the relationship between damping ratio and mass for a physics experiment, but I am unable to find any values of the damping coefficient $c$. Firstly, does the damping coefficient apply to the material of the spring or the medium (air in my case)? Secondly, is there a generally accepted value for $c$?

Comment: Damping coefficient, strictly speaking is a property of both the object and the medium. However to a good approximation, it can be modelled as a property of medium alone.

Answer (score -1):

The damping coefficient is dependent on the medium as well as the material which is performing the motion. For example a spring will have a bit of internal friction and the air, here the medium, will add up some air resistqnce too. 
The typical formula for dampened oscillations is

$$y(t)=Ae^{-ct} \cdot sin( \omega t)$$

As others have already mentioned, there is no fixed value for the damping coefficient c.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The spring I am using is made of steel, and it oscillates in the air. Do you know how I would measure my value for c? Could you also help me to define the terms in equation above?

Comment: Additionally, if a value for c is constant for the same spring oscillating under the same conditions right? It should not change over time?

Comment: Measuring the dampening constant should be easy: First note down the amplitude at which the oscillator starts swinging. Then write down how much the amplitude changed after a time t. Example: You start with A, but after 10 seconds A is half times big. Caöculate c for $$0.5A=Ae^{-c \cdot 10s} <=> c=?$$

Comment: I am changing the mass to see how damping ratio changes. I'm expecting the damping ratio to change, which means A changes at different rates depending on the mass attached. Doesn't that mean my value of c would change for every mass?